# How to run CREATE DATABASE command on LIVE Laravel site through get request

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-artisan, liveserver

**Background:**

- I've inherited a Laravel PHP codebase and needed to make some minor changes.
- I added a page with a button that invokes this method below to create a database on the fly.
- This works on my machine in dev, fails with 500 error on live.
- If I comment out this line, the redirect works fine, so I know this is the issue.

I know this isn't ideal, but it's what I want to do.  How can I make this command work please?

**Method I added:**

```
public function store()
{
    $datestr = date("Y_H_i_s");
    DB::statement("CREATE DATABASE xxxx_". $datestr);
    return redirect()->to('/setupfinished');
}
```

Edit: Here's the error message - so how do I enable permissions for this user?

```
[previous exception] [object] (PDOException(code: 42000): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1044 Access denied for user 'xxxx'@'localhost' to database 'xxxx_2024_19_14_10' at /var/www/summer/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:580)
[stacktrace]
```

Treat me as if I know nothing about Laravel but I do know some PHP.

Thanks!

Comment: This is causing an error, so check where errors are being logged to and add the message to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for help - I fixed with mysql command:

```
grant all privileges on *.* to '<user>'@'localhost';
```

Answer (score 1):

If it works on local environment, then the issue might be with the database permissions on the server.
Make sure the DB_USERNAME you have in .env file on server has permission to create database.

Comment: This could be a comment in order to find a solution